# Using quotes in Google Sheets named functions

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to turn the following into a custom named function in Google Sheets:

=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SK5z-Lwy48FNl92Xy9i4agfui17fLVHJCstSC3aNwa0/edit#gid=985171355&range=G"&COUNTA('Sheet1'!G:G), "Sheet1")

ie so that the link takes you to the last row in column G of Sheet1.  I want to define the function so I can use an argument for the Sheet1 reference.

I've tried lots of variations (playing around with the quotes) of the following but I always get a parsing error:

`=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SK5z-Lwy48FNl92Xy9i4agfui17fLVHJCstSC3aNwa0/edit#gid=985171355&range=G"&COUNTA(&"'"&sheetname&"'"&!G:G), sheetname)`

If this function is named GOTO_SHEET, it would be called using the following: =GOTO_SHEET("sheetx"), is how I envisage using this.  The placeholder sheetname would be replaced with 'sheetx' (sorry to be obvious).

I can't get this to work at all - any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this `formula definition` within **named function** creation:*

```js
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SK5z-Lwy48FNl92Xy9i4agfui17fLVHJCstSC3aNwa0/edit#gid=985171355&range=G"&COUNTA(indirect(sheetname&"!G:G")), "Sheet1")
```

***Argument Placeholder***: `sheetname`

---

***Scenario 2** to include both `gid_value` & `sheetname`*

```js
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19cZl8YvP8Xl4prU5j78GkJjQ40_rkzBNkWcJlJuMlME/edit#gid="&gid_value&"range=G"&COUNTA(indirect(sheetname&"!G:G")), "Sheet1")
```

***Argument Placeholders***:

`gid_value`

`sheetname`

Comment: Thank you!  That totally works but I realised I left something out in my original request.  Is there a way for the argument placeholder to also reference which tab in the sheet the hyperlink should go to?  As in, if the placeholder = Sheet2, the link goes to that cell reference in Sheet2?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include both `gid number` of the tab + `sheetname`